# Disappear keyboard in uitextview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

i'm using uitextview in swift and for keyboard disappear i'm using uitextview delegate method

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

but i don't want to use this delegate method to return the keyboard bcz i want to use return key for next line.
is there any other ways to disappear keyboard?
and for some reason i don't wana use touch event.

Comment: You are adding gesture outside of keyboard to dismiss it.

Comment: i used that but for some reasons i don't wana use gesture. because when i use gesture it disable some functionality.

Comment: please remove "return false" and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have both a return and a dismiss key on the keyboard unless you use a custom keyboard. A custom keyboard can be added by setting the `inputView` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/inputView)

A better standard practice is to have a button on top of the keyboard giving the user an option to hide it. This can be done by assigning an `inputAccessoryView` for the `UITextView`. More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/inputAccessoryView)

Answer (score 1):

Try using ToolBar

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    ...


    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)

    var nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "nextTextfield")
    var previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "previousTextfield")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBar.setItems([previousButton, spaceButton, nextButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    textField.delegate = self
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

func nextTextfield() {
    nextTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func previousTextfield() {
   //if exist previous        
   //previousTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
self.view!.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add done tool bar on your keyboard.On that done action you can resign your keyboard

Comment: i was  also thinking  to add toolbar. but is it not possible to add return key and next line in keyboard?

Comment: at a time you can use only one key in keyboard other wise you have to use custome made keyboard (third party keyboard). . . In My opinion use done tool bar . . It is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use IQKeboardManager Class available for both Swift and objective C.

For swift code written below will help you.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
}
```

Link given below will help you.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager